# Can't install python library properly

Tags: python, anaconda

I tried to install the python portfolio optimization library with the following command

```
!pip install pyportfolioopt
```

[Link](https://pypi.org/project/pyportfolioopt/) to the library's documentation

However I get the following error output when I try to execute the command both in Jupyter notebook and conda command prompt. Any help would be appreciated. I really cant seem to figure a way around it.

```
Collecting pyportfolioopt
  Using cached PyPortfolioOpt-1.4.1-py3-none-any.whl (56 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: pandas>=0.19 in c:\users\aden\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from pyportfolioopt) (1.1.3)
Requirement already satisfied: scipy<2.0,>=1.3 in c:\users\aden\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from pyportfolioopt) (1.5.2)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy<2.0,>=1.12 in c:\users\aden\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from pyportfolioopt) (1.19.2)
Collecting cvxpy<2.0.0,>=1.1.10
  Using cached cvxpy-1.1.12-cp38-cp38-win_amd64.whl (827 kB)
Collecting scs>=1.1.6
  Using cached scs-2.1.3.tar.gz (147 kB)
Collecting osqp>=0.4.1
  Using cached osqp-0.6.2.post0-cp38-cp38-win_amd64.whl (162 kB)
Collecting ecos>=2
  Using cached ecos-2.0.7.post1.tar.gz (126 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: qdldl in c:\users\aden\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from osqp>=0.4.1->cvxpy<2.0.0,>=1.1.10->pyportfolioopt) (0.1.5.post0)
Requirement already satisfied: pytz>=2017.2 in c:\users\aden\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from pandas>=0.19->pyportfolioopt) (2020.1)
Requirement already satisfied: python-dateutil>=2.7.3 in c:\users\aden\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from pandas>=0.19->pyportfolioopt) (2.8.1)
Requirement already satisfied: six>=1.5 in c:\users\aden\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from python-dateutil>=2.7.3->pandas>=0.19->pyportfolioopt) (1.15.0)
Building wheels for collected packages: ecos, scs
  Building wheel for ecos (setup.py): started
  Building wheel for ecos (setup.py): finished with status 'error'
  Running setup.py clean for ecos
  Building wheel for scs (setup.py): started
  Building wheel for scs (setup.py): finished with status 'error'
  Running setup.py clean for scs
Failed to build ecos scs
Installing collected packages: scs, osqp, ecos, cvxpy, pyportfolioopt
    Running setup.py install for scs: started
    Running setup.py install for scs: finished with status 'error'
Note: you may need to restart the kernel to use updated packages.
WARNING: Value for scheme.headers does not match. Please report this to <https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/9617>
distutils: C:\Users\aden\anaconda3\Include\UNKNOWN
sysconfig: C:\Users\aden\anaconda3\Include
WARNING: Additional context:
user = False
home = None
root = None
prefix = None
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: 'C:\Users\aden\anaconda3\python.exe' -u -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\aden\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-z2ri1hp7\\ecos_3a18f791998743eb89798898651c5f90\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\aden\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-z2ri1hp7\\ecos_3a18f791998743eb89798898651c5f90\\setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__) if os.path.exists(__file__) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' bdist_wheel -d 'C:\Users\aden\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-wheel-rvqsqp1j'
       cwd: C:\Users\aden\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-z2ri1hp7\ecos_3a18f791998743eb89798898651c5f90\
  Complete output (12 lines):
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_py
  creating build
  creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.8
  creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\ecos
  copying src\ecos\ecos.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\ecos
  copying src\ecos\version.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\ecos
  copying src\ecos\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\ecos
  running build_ext
  building '_ecos' extension
  error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required. Get it with "Microsoft C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/
  ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for ecos
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: 'C:\Users\aden\anaconda3\python.exe' -u -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\aden\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-z2ri1hp7\\scs_9eedcd8428e8499dbe61698521ace3ee\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\aden\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-z2ri1hp7\\scs_9eedcd8428e8499dbe61698521ace3ee\\setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__) if os.path.exists(__file__) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' bdist_wheel -d 'C:\Users\aden\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-wheel-tqc1q05z'
       cwd: C:\Users\aden\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-z2ri1hp7\scs_9eedcd8428e8499dbe61698521ace3ee\
  Complete output (90 lines):
  Namespace(blas64=False, extraverbose=False, float32=False, gpu=False, gpu_atrans=True, int32=False, scs=False)
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_py
  creating build
  creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.8
  creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\scs
  copying src\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\scs
  running build_ext
  blas_mkl_info:
      libraries = ['mkl_rt']
      library_dirs = ['C:/Users/aden/anaconda3\\Library\\lib']
      define_macros = [('SCIPY_MKL_H', None), ('HAVE_CBLAS', None)]
      include_dirs = ['C:/Users/aden/anaconda3\\Library\\include']
  blas_opt_info:
      libraries = ['mkl_rt']
      library_dirs = ['C:/Users/aden/anaconda3\\Library\\lib']
      define_macros = [('SCIPY_MKL_H', None), ('HAVE_CBLAS', None)]
      include_dirs = ['C:/Users/aden/anaconda3\\Library\\include']
  lapack_mkl_info:
      libraries = ['mkl_rt']
      library_dirs = ['C:/Users/aden/anaconda3\\Library\\lib']
      define_macros = [('SCIPY_MKL_H', None), ('HAVE_CBLAS', None)]
      include_dirs = ['C:/Users/aden/anaconda3\\Library\\include']
  lapack_opt_info:
      libraries = ['mkl_rt']
      library_dirs = ['C:/Users/aden/anaconda3\\Library\\lib']
      define_macros = [('SCIPY_MKL_H', None), ('HAVE_CBLAS', None)]
      include_dirs = ['C:/Users/aden/anaconda3\\Library\\include']
  Could not locate executable g77
  Could not locate executable f77
  Could not locate executable ifort
  Could not locate executable ifl
  Could not locate executable f90
  Could not locate executable DF
  Could not locate executable efl
  Using built-in specs.
  COLLECT_GCC=C:\MinGW\bin\gfortran.exe
  COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=c:/mingw/bin/../libexec/gcc/mingw32/6.3.0/lto-wrapper.exe
  Target: mingw32
  Configured with: ../src/gcc-6.3.0/configure --build=x86_64-pc-linux-gnu --host=mingw32 --with-gmp=/mingw --with-mpfr=/mingw --with-mpc=/mingw --with-isl=/mingw --prefix=/mingw --disable-win32-registry --target=mingw32 --with-arch=i586 --enable-languages=c,c++,objc,obj-c++,fortran,ada --with-pkgversion='MinGW.org GCC-6.3.0-1' --enable-static --enable-shared --enable-threads --with-dwarf2 --disable-sjlj-exceptions --enable-version-specific-runtime-libs --with-libiconv-prefix=/mingw --with-libintl-prefix=/mingw --enable-libstdcxx-debug --with-tune=generic --enable-libgomp --disable-libvtv --enable-nls
  Thread model: win32
  gcc version 6.3.0 (MinGW.org GCC-6.3.0-1)
  C:\Users\aden\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:1914: UserWarning:
      Optimized (vendor) Blas libraries are not found.
      Falls back to netlib Blas library which has worse performance.
      A better performance should be easily gained by switching
      Blas library.
    if self._calc_info(blas):
  C:\Users\aden\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:1914: UserWarning:
      Blas (http://www.netlib.org/blas/) libraries not found.
      Directories to search for the libraries can be specified in the
      numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [blas]) or by setting
      the BLAS environment variable.
    if self._calc_info(blas):
  C:\Users\aden\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:1914: UserWarning:
      Blas (http://www.netlib.org/blas/) sources not found.
      Directories to search for the sources can be specified in the
      numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [blas_src]) or by setting
      the BLAS_SRC environment variable.
    if self._calc_info(blas):
  Using built-in specs.
  COLLECT_GCC=C:\MinGW\bin\gfortran.exe
  COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=c:/mingw/bin/../libexec/gcc/mingw32/6.3.0/lto-wrapper.exe
  Target: mingw32
  Configured with: ../src/gcc-6.3.0/configure --build=x86_64-pc-linux-gnu --host=mingw32 --with-gmp=/mingw --with-mpfr=/mingw --with-mpc=/mingw --with-isl=/mingw --prefix=/mingw --disable-win32-registry --target=mingw32 --with-arch=i586 --enable-languages=c,c++,objc,obj-c++,fortran,ada --with-pkgversion='MinGW.org GCC-6.3.0-1' --enable-static --enable-shared --enable-threads --with-dwarf2 --disable-sjlj-exceptions --enable-version-specific-runtime-libs --with-libiconv-prefix=/mingw --with-libintl-prefix=/mingw --enable-libstdcxx-debug --with-tune=generic --enable-libgomp --disable-libvtv --enable-nls
  Thread model: win32
  gcc version 6.3.0 (MinGW.org GCC-6.3.0-1)
  Using built-in specs.
  COLLECT_GCC=C:\MinGW\bin\gfortran.exe
  COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=c:/mingw/bin/../libexec/gcc/mingw32/6.3.0/lto-wrapper.exe
  Target: mingw32
  Configured with: ../src/gcc-6.3.0/configure --build=x86_64-pc-linux-gnu --host=mingw32 --with-gmp=/mingw --with-mpfr=/mingw --with-mpc=/mingw --with-isl=/mingw --prefix=/mingw --disable-win32-registry --target=mingw32 --with-arch=i586 --enable-languages=c,c++,objc,obj-c++,fortran,ada --with-pkgversion='MinGW.org GCC-6.3.0-1' --enable-static --enable-shared --enable-threads --with-dwarf2 --disable-sjlj-exceptions --enable-version-specific-runtime-libs --with-libiconv-prefix=/mingw --with-libintl-prefix=/mingw --enable-libstdcxx-debug --with-tune=generic --enable-libgomp --disable-libvtv --enable-nls
  Thread model: win32
  gcc version 6.3.0 (MinGW.org GCC-6.3.0-1)
  C:\Users\aden\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:1748: UserWarning:
      Lapack (http://www.netlib.org/lapack/) libraries not found.
      Directories to search for the libraries can be specified in the
      numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [lapack]) or by setting
      the LAPACK environment variable.
    return getattr(self, '_calc_info_{}'.format(name))()
  C:\Users\aden\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:1748: UserWarning:
      Lapack (http://www.netlib.org/lapack/) sources not found.
      Directories to search for the sources can be specified in the
      numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [lapack_src]) or by setting
      the LAPACK_SRC environment variable.
    return getattr(self, '_calc_info_{}'.format(name))()
  error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required. Get it with "Microsoft C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/
  {}
  {}
  ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for scs
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'C:\Users\aden\anaconda3\python.exe' -u -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\aden\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-z2ri1hp7\\scs_9eedcd8428e8499dbe61698521ace3ee\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\aden\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-z2ri1hp7\\scs_9eedcd8428e8499dbe61698521ace3ee\\setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__) if os.path.exists(__file__) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\aden\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-399muuf3\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'C:\Users\aden\anaconda3\Include\scs'
         cwd: C:\Users\aden\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-z2ri1hp7\scs_9eedcd8428e8499dbe61698521ace3ee\
    Complete output (90 lines):
    Namespace(blas64=False, extraverbose=False, float32=False, gpu=False, gpu_atrans=True, int32=False, scs=False)
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.8
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\scs
    copying src\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\scs
    running build_ext
    blas_mkl_info:
        libraries = ['mkl_rt']
        library_dirs = ['C:/Users/aden/anaconda3\\Library\\lib']
        define_macros = [('SCIPY_MKL_H', None), ('HAVE_CBLAS', None)]
        include_dirs = ['C:/Users/aden/anaconda3\\Library\\include']
    blas_opt_info:
        libraries = ['mkl_rt']
        library_dirs = ['C:/Users/aden/anaconda3\\Library\\lib']
        define_macros = [('SCIPY_MKL_H', None), ('HAVE_CBLAS', None)]
        include_dirs = ['C:/Users/aden/anaconda3\\Library\\include']
    lapack_mkl_info:
        libraries = ['mkl_rt']
        library_dirs = ['C:/Users/aden/anaconda3\\Library\\lib']
        define_macros = [('SCIPY_MKL_H', None), ('HAVE_CBLAS', None)]
        include_dirs = ['C:/Users/aden/anaconda3\\Library\\include']
    lapack_opt_info:
        libraries = ['mkl_rt']
        library_dirs = ['C:/Users/aden/anaconda3\\Library\\lib']
        define_macros = [('SCIPY_MKL_H', None), ('HAVE_CBLAS', None)]
        include_dirs = ['C:/Users/aden/anaconda3\\Library\\include']
    Could not locate executable g77
    Could not locate executable f77
    Could not locate executable ifort
    Could not locate executable ifl
    Could not locate executable f90
    Could not locate executable DF
    Could not locate executable efl
    Using built-in specs.
    COLLECT_GCC=C:\MinGW\bin\gfortran.exe
    COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=c:/mingw/bin/../libexec/gcc/mingw32/6.3.0/lto-wrapper.exe
    Target: mingw32
    Configured with: ../src/gcc-6.3.0/configure --build=x86_64-pc-linux-gnu --host=mingw32 --with-gmp=/mingw --with-mpfr=/mingw --with-mpc=/mingw --with-isl=/mingw --prefix=/mingw --disable-win32-registry --target=mingw32 --with-arch=i586 --enable-languages=c,c++,objc,obj-c++,fortran,ada --with-pkgversion='MinGW.org GCC-6.3.0-1' --enable-static --enable-shared --enable-threads --with-dwarf2 --disable-sjlj-exceptions --enable-version-specific-runtime-libs --with-libiconv-prefix=/mingw --with-libintl-prefix=/mingw --enable-libstdcxx-debug --with-tune=generic --enable-libgomp --disable-libvtv --enable-nls
    Thread model: win32
    gcc version 6.3.0 (MinGW.org GCC-6.3.0-1)
    C:\Users\aden\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:1914: UserWarning:
        Optimized (vendor) Blas libraries are not found.
        Falls back to netlib Blas library which has worse performance.
        A better performance should be easily gained by switching
        Blas library.
      if self._calc_info(blas):
    C:\Users\aden\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:1914: UserWarning:
        Blas (http://www.netlib.org/blas/) libraries not found.
        Directories to search for the libraries can be specified in the
        numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [blas]) or by setting
        the BLAS environment variable.
      if self._calc_info(blas):
    C:\Users\aden\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:1914: UserWarning:
        Blas (http://www.netlib.org/blas/) sources not found.
        Directories to search for the sources can be specified in the
        numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [blas_src]) or by setting
        the BLAS_SRC environment variable.
      if self._calc_info(blas):
    Using built-in specs.
    COLLECT_GCC=C:\MinGW\bin\gfortran.exe
    COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=c:/mingw/bin/../libexec/gcc/mingw32/6.3.0/lto-wrapper.exe
    Target: mingw32
    Configured with: ../src/gcc-6.3.0/configure --build=x86_64-pc-linux-gnu --host=mingw32 --with-gmp=/mingw --with-mpfr=/mingw --with-mpc=/mingw --with-isl=/mingw --prefix=/mingw --disable-win32-registry --target=mingw32 --with-arch=i586 --enable-languages=c,c++,objc,obj-c++,fortran,ada --with-pkgversion='MinGW.org GCC-6.3.0-1' --enable-static --enable-shared --enable-threads --with-dwarf2 --disable-sjlj-exceptions --enable-version-specific-runtime-libs --with-libiconv-prefix=/mingw --with-libintl-prefix=/mingw --enable-libstdcxx-debug --with-tune=generic --enable-libgomp --disable-libvtv --enable-nls
    Thread model: win32
    gcc version 6.3.0 (MinGW.org GCC-6.3.0-1)
    Using built-in specs.
    COLLECT_GCC=C:\MinGW\bin\gfortran.exe
    COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=c:/mingw/bin/../libexec/gcc/mingw32/6.3.0/lto-wrapper.exe
    Target: mingw32
    Configured with: ../src/gcc-6.3.0/configure --build=x86_64-pc-linux-gnu --host=mingw32 --with-gmp=/mingw --with-mpfr=/mingw --with-mpc=/mingw --with-isl=/mingw --prefix=/mingw --disable-win32-registry --target=mingw32 --with-arch=i586 --enable-languages=c,c++,objc,obj-c++,fortran,ada --with-pkgversion='MinGW.org GCC-6.3.0-1' --enable-static --enable-shared --enable-threads --with-dwarf2 --disable-sjlj-exceptions --enable-version-specific-runtime-libs --with-libiconv-prefix=/mingw --with-libintl-prefix=/mingw --enable-libstdcxx-debug --with-tune=generic --enable-libgomp --disable-libvtv --enable-nls
    Thread model: win32
    gcc version 6.3.0 (MinGW.org GCC-6.3.0-1)
    C:\Users\aden\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:1748: UserWarning:
        Lapack (http://www.netlib.org/lapack/) libraries not found.
        Directories to search for the libraries can be specified in the
        numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [lapack]) or by setting
        the LAPACK environment variable.
      return getattr(self, '_calc_info_{}'.format(name))()
    C:\Users\aden\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:1748: UserWarning:
        Lapack (http://www.netlib.org/lapack/) sources not found.
        Directories to search for the sources can be specified in the
        numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [lapack_src]) or by setting
        the LAPACK_SRC environment variable.
      return getattr(self, '_calc_info_{}'.format(name))()
    error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required. Get it with "Microsoft C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/
    {}
    {}
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'C:\Users\aden\anaconda3\python.exe' -u -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\aden\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-z2ri1hp7\\scs_9eedcd8428e8499dbe61698521ace3ee\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\aden\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-z2ri1hp7\\scs_9eedcd8428e8499dbe61698521ace3ee\\setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__) if os.path.exists(__file__) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\aden\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-399muuf3\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'C:\Users\aden\anaconda3\Include\scs' Check the logs for full command output.
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you have installed visual c++ before, if yes try to update to 14.0 by following
link- https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/

Comment: I don't get why it has anything to do with Visual C++? I'm trying to install a python library. I do have Visual Studio Code installed and I could uninstall it altogether as I don't use it. Would that solve the problem?

Comment: visual studio code does not have any impact on this. sometimes python libraries does requires c++ environment try to install visual c++ first